# Global editing of CiviCRM fields

Tags: contacts, contact-types

How can I globally edit a particular CiviCRM Contact field?  For example, I would like to search for a specific set of contacts, then assign them all a particular Contact Subtype.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible using Update contact using profile. Below are the step to achieve this

1. Create a Profile with Contact Sub-type field.
   [image]

   [image]
2. Do Contact Search and select contact(s) you want to update and select '**Update multiple contacts**' from **Actions** dropdown.

[image]

3. You will be redirected to Profile selection page. Select the profile you had created at #1 from 'select profile' dropdown and click on continue.

[image]

4. You will be redirected to a page where you wii see fields against each contact. Select the contact subtype for each contact and then click on Update Contacts. You can also click on Copy image [image](besides column title) to copy the content of 1st field into rest of fields beneath it.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep